# EditText having a value before entering some text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am an android beginner. I am stuck up with a problem. I'm having three `EditTexts` to which I need to do validation. When I'm doing validation, the EditText is having a value even though I didn't enter any value while running the application. To check whether which value is present, I printed the values using `System.out.println()`

This is printed in the logcat

```
08-06 06:53:12.235: I/System.out(3801): 
android.widget.EditText{40fca498 VFED..CL......I. 0,254-480,299 #7f05000c app:id/vTypeModel}
android.widget.EditText{40fc9f58 VFED..CL ......I. 0,180-480,225 #7f05000b app:id/vTypeMake}   
android.widget.EditText{40fccd48 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,106-480,151 #7f05000a app:id/vTypeNumber}
```

Where did these values come from? Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you post your code of java file and xml also?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: we are unable to help until you post some code here @David said .From logcat it is not understandable where and why you are getting exception

Comment: Those are not the values inside the EditText. you must use mEditText.getText().toString(); to fetch the text in it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to include getText() method during validation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `System.out.println(EditText object)`

If that's the case, then that is not the value inside `object` that is being printed, you need to use `object.getText().toString()`

Else post your code.